# c# strong name assembly reflection load interface cast problem

Tags: c#, dll, casting, .net-assembly

I have isolated a following issue I am using for distributed measurement and data interpretation (when the impl knows how to handle the data and its UserControl which is not present int the example represents them).

I have 3 different projects in solution:
1) the interface (separate dll)

```
namespace inter
{
    public interface IInter
    {
        byte[] results();
    }
}
```

2) implementing class (separate dll)

```
using inter;

namespace impl
{
    public class impl : IInter
    {
        public byte[] results()
        {//dummy data production
            return new byte[10].Select((ii, index) => (byte)index).ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

3) program that runs the issue...

```
using inter;
using impl;

namespace test_class_casting
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var path = @"C:\Users\pavel\source\repos\test class casting\impl\bin\Debug\impl.dll";
            var b = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
            var assembly = Assembly.Load(b);

            IInter inst = null;
            var expTypes = assembly.GetExportedTypes();
            foreach (var d in assembly.GetExportedTypes())
            {
                var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(d);
                if (obj is IInter)
                {
                    inst = obj as IInter;
                    try
                    {
                        var res = inst.results();
                        continue;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                        Console.ReadKey();
                        Environment.Exit(0);
                    }
                }
            }

            try
            {
                var reType = (impl.impl)inst;// as impl.impl;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Console.ReadKey();
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is the reType cast will fail because *[A]impl.impl cannot be cast to [B]impl.impl.* exception message. **How can I make wotk the script recognize both class types are the same.** (Note. I cannot link the reference into the project, the implementing *impl* classes are the responsibility of the users, so I do not even know them all.

I tried even to add a Strong names to both inter and impl but with now progress. Do you have plese the solution for this?

Comment: You say that "I cannot link the reference into the project, the implementing impl classes are the responsibility of the users, so I do not even know them all" but you are trying to cast to `impl.impl`. This is a contradiction.

Comment: If you are programming to abstraction, you should not know impl namespace, let alone impl.impl type. Why casting there at all?

Comment: This happens because you are loading an assembly into your AppDomain which is already there. You will have two assemblies of the same origin then.  I can produce an answer (to make your code interpret the created instance as impl.impl), but don't want to until you explain why you are already referencing the impl assembly here.

Comment: I want to cast to the real type because it is in real app happening int the KernelUserControl which knouws how to use other properties and fields of impl class. The pattern should be impl has cetain properties and fleld that are use in result() method to produce result. The result method is called as inter to produce result somewhere (not in the computer but in another), Then the result come back to the main computer along with the inter instance (with right fields/properties values that were used for measurement) and I want to cast that instance into its real type, but I cannot...

Comment: I know I can use reflection to exctract the fields and properties values and apply them to value I am trying to cast here. But it is not handy for the users I have, I want to make them the work as simple as possible.

Comment: "Then the result come back to the main computer along with the inter instance" how this is achieved? Because in the posted code, you are just trying to load an assembly dynamically and create instances of all the exposed classes. In this case, are all these classes extend from impl.impl, or just implement inter.Inter? Because if not, this cast will always fail. `public byte[] results()` is not abstract nor virtual. Can you please add en example class which you get by `assembly.GetExportedTypes()`

Comment: This is just extraction of the code, trust me, the instance is comming along the data (in reality from db). Actualy I do not understand, what you are asking for. Here is a simple example (isolated from larger software that ilustratess the issue). What I am asking, Is it possible to make the cast working? I was trying the strong naming of the assemblies, it this the way? How to fix it, or this is not absolutely possible?

Comment: There must be a way when I am loading the class (type) from anywhere and it has strong name, that should be recognized that already one such type is already loaded in the project...(while the second is loaded in runtime, it should be recognized that the impl.impl type is already in the game...but how?

Comment: What I am asking is; you are referencing impl.impl in your project. You are then dynamically loading an assembly into your AppDomain and expect all the exposed classes in it to be of type impl.impl. This is only possible when all these classes extend impl.impl. Is this the case? It is important for me because I reproduced the issue and should know that when I post an answer it is a working solution.

Comment: I do not mean to extend impl.impl. The example to download is here https://www.dropbox.com/s/p2z1kjs6tb9p3rt/test%20class%20casting.zip?dl=0

Comment: Imagine the user would like to make its own module base on inter. The main app accepts the valid implementation of the user inter which is named in this example impl.impl. The main app saves the impl.impl as a byte[] into db and distribute the impl.impl to all measuring leaf apps (the leafs are changing some fields and properties of impl.impl (in the example are none fields and properties) and then the leaf uses the impl.impl to call the result(),

Comment: then it takes the result byte[] and the changed impl.impl (still handled as a inter) and send it back to main app where it is sent to ImplUserControl. The impl user control knows that the inter obtained is the impl.impl type, so it is trying to cast to its original type to be able to use its fields and properties...(note. in the leafs the fields and properties are handled by reflection and it works), but here I want to provide the original impl.impl

Comment: (the user creating the ImplUserControl should have as simple as possible - most of my users do not know what is reflection at all, but they know basics of classes, fields and properties for sure...)

Comment: Please anybody...

Comment: Dear Pavel. I really want to help you on this. But I am still trying to understand how your design works. Can you please answer the following; 1. You are referencing a pre-built version of "impl" assembly with an "impl" class 2. someone implements another assembly and a class with the same name so that it is like "impl.impl" 3. You get this others' assembly from DB and load it and try to cast it to your pre-built "impl.impl"? are all these correct?

Comment: Because if this is the situation (you are referencing a prebuilt impl.impl and then try to load ANOTHER impl.impl into AppDomain and cast), I don't expect it to work.

Comment: Thank you Oguz for answer. Ad 1) yes, exactly, Ad2) no, I expect no (at least at this example), the impl.impl came all from same source and are of very same version

Comment: Ad 3) in DB there is just byte[] content of the impl.impl file nothing more (the content is the same as I am reading by Assembly.Load and referencing in the project....)

Comment: If the impl.impl differs I know they will be different runtime too..

Comment: Sorry, supper break. Can you come to chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210683/discussion-between-oguz-ozgul-and-pavel-kudrna).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all, after some assemblies studying I found a solution. Everytime the assembly is loading dynamically, the code can check whether it is already in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() (check by FullName property). I.e. if the assembly is referenced to the project.

If none exists the new assembly is used and instances from its GetExportedTypes() are created.

If already exists, then the already loaded one is used for instances creation. The Example code is here https://www.dropbox.com/s/hbs0ndwh8cf3uq0/test%20class%20casting-resolved.zip?dl=0